# comparando uma variável com um vetor ou lista

Tags: java, if, arraylist, condição

Geralmente para realizar uma condicional utilizando um vetor ou uma lista e necessário realizar um for e realizar o if linha por linha dessa forma.

```
//sendo item uma string e listaItens um List<String>
for(String lista: listaItens){
    if(item.equal(lista){
       return true;
    }
}
```

gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais efetiva de realizar essa operação onde o propio if já faça a comparação com toda a lista sem necessidade do for por exemplo `if(variavel.equal(lista.asItem)` ou algo do genero.

Comment: O que você pretende com esse código? Achar apenas um valor igual ou todos que forem iguais?

Comment: somente achar um igual, preciso saber se a variável possui o valor igual a um dos elementos da lista, se sim eu sou obrigado a usar esse valor, se não eu tenho que ignorar o valor contida na variável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem o método contains, que pertence a classe ArrayList. 
Segue um exemplo básico, do que você quer:

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
  lista.add("Ola");
  lista.add("Mundo");
  String mundo = "Mundo";
if (lista.contains(mundo)) {
  System.out.println("Achou!");
}
```

Agora, falar com precisão se essa implementação é mais efetiva que a outra, acho que não, pois se tratando de busca em uma lista sempre será percorrido todos os itens da lista.

Comment: Na verdade é `List.contains`.

Comment: Me expressei mal, mas melhorei um pouco a resposta!

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar a expressao lambda(função sem declaração) na função forEach

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2d", "sf3", "fgfd4", "fgdf5", "6", "7");


list.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n.equals("sf3")?"achou":""));
```

Comment: Isso funciona com string?

Comment: Testei com string e funcionou                                                  
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2d", "sf3", "fgfd4", "fgdf5", "6", "7");
 list.forEach(n -> System.out.println(n.equals("sf3")));

Comment: A ideia era eliminar o laço e obter um `boolean` disso (veja o `return true` no código do OP). Tudo o que você fez foi fazer um laço com um lambda, mas continua sendo um laço e não fornece um `boolean`.